# Compiler error with no line number

Tags: ios, swift

Whwn trying to compile my project, the following error appears in AppCode (Xcode only prints the "Error: Command... part"):

AppCode:
`Note:Stored value type does not match pointer operand type!
Note:  store %CSo7UIColor* %135, %objc_object** %136, align 8, !dbg !4686
Error: %objc_object*LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
Error:Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1`

Is there a way to actually get the line number causing the problem ? Note says something related to UIColor but that's the only thing I got from it :S

P.S: I have deleted Derived Data, checked out a previous commit, created a new project and still the same issue. I'm almost certain that the problem is due to a dependency.

Comment: Why don't you show your code? More specifically the UIColor code.

Comment: Obviously crashing the compiler is undesired behavior, and Xcode does not help you track down the issue. It may not even really be your fault. What I do in these situations is use a binary search. I comment things out progressively until I find the region of my code that's crashing the compiler.

Comment: @leonardo-savio-dabus I would but I'm not even sure if a) It's something in my code or b) Pod's code.

Comment: @nts You should delete also Xcode caches

Comment: @matt I feared that :( Thought maybe there was a way to get more info from a log or similar to track down the file causing the problema at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem...

`self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : .clearColor()]`

`.clearColor()` should work...Fixed it by appending UIColor back.

Comment: Why do you say that `.clearColor()` should work? Unless it's been overridden, `titleTextAttributes` is a `[NSObject: AnyObject]`, and the compiler has nothing to infer the class.

Comment: Have you reported the bug?

Comment: Had to replicate everything from the last commit (which to begin with was a terrible idea since I grouped tons of things...never again)... @zsneak: Will do it asap